# WPF Loading controls taking huge time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a string array like

```
string[] strngData  = new string[] {"12","11","23","34"};
```

This string array length may be up to 4000. I need create a textbox for each string and loading all the text boxes inside a stackpanel within scrollviewer.

As the number of strings increases and number of textboxes increases resulting, the time to render the controls to UI is taking more time. for displaying 4000+ strings it is taking around 18+ secs.

Is there a way to improve the rendering time?

Comment: Are all the textboxes going to be viewed by the user at once?

Comment: Load only some of them at a time. Load 100, then when the user scrolls down, load 100 more and so on.

Comment: Why textboxes at all? Why not, say, a listview or some such that's designed to take this kind of data?

Comment: @piyush at a time user can see 112 text boxes

Comment: @Vasile Can you please suggest some code to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n place of stackpanel you may use ListView (which has inbuild deferred UI loading) with custom ItemTemplate and ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
<ListView Name="x" ItemsSource="..." HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=/}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

There are some key moments: you have to use VirtualizingStackPanel in ItemsPanel template in place of usual StackPanel; TextBox.Text binding path have to be equal to `/`(working with current item); I also test the example for ObservaleCollection so using of List may disallow you to edit items position, count, etc.

Comment: UI virtualization should be enabled by default for ListViews, so you don't need to explicitly set an ItemsPanel template.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, I set ItemsPanel cos op will most likely change default template to  fix margins or padding and the example will not work.